# Syntax error at or near WHERE clause, Natural join

Tags: sql, syntax-error, isqlquery

Why does this code not work?: (If I remove book_info and author in the 'where' clause, it still doesn't work).

```
SELECT title, last_name 
FROM book_info NATURAL JOIN book_author natural join author
WHERE book_info.title = ‘Uncle Samsonite’ AND author.last_name = ‘Shakespeare’;
```

The error message I get is:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Samsonite’" 
> LINE 3: WHERE book_info.title = ‘Uncle Samsonite’ AND author.last_na...

Without the 'where' clause it looks like this:
[image: Picture]

Comment: are you using a back-tick instead of a single quote? ' vs `

Comment: I'm using a single quote: ' not `@John

Comment: If you pasted your code in here it looks like it's using an apostrophe ‘ not a single quote '.  

what editor are you using? I've noticed when writing things on a mac in textedit or in the slack input it will change what i type to something else.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked!! Once you go Mac, you always go back @John